# Executing a code after a promise with nested promises inside it is resolved

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, web3js

I have the following js code structure;

```
Promise_1.then(function(){
  for(){
    Promise2.then(function(){
      ...
    })
  }
}).then(
  Promise_3.then(function(){
    for(){
      Promise4.then(function(){
        ...
      })
    }
  })
).then(
  function(){
    // SOME CODE
  }
)
```

I want to execute SOME CODE after the above promises are resolved. But the SOME CODE is executing before the above promises are resolved. I know I can enclose SOME CODE in `setTimeout()` which will solve the problem as suggested by other answers on SO but I think it's not a good idea. The actual code on which I am working is as follow;

```
user_xp = 0
connections_blocks.methods.get_deposit_blocks(current_email).call({
    from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
}, function (err, result) {
    deposit_blocks = result
    console.log(deposit_blocks)
    deposit_blocks = deposit_blocks.split(",")
    deposit_blocks.splice(0, 1)
    for (i_ in deposit_blocks) {
        console.log(deposit_blocks[i_])
        user_xp + new_web3.eth.getBlock(deposit_blocks[i_]).then(function (deposit_block) {
            user_xp = user_xp + deposit_block.gasUsed
            console.log(user_xp)
        })
    }
}).then(
    connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks(current_email).call({
        from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
    }, function (err, result) {
        send_blocks = result
        console.log(send_blocks)
        send_blocks = send_blocks.split(",")
        send_blocks.splice(0, 1)
        for (i_ = 0; i_ < send_blocks.length; i_ = i_ + 2) {
            console.log(send_blocks[i_])
            user_xp + new_web3.eth.getBlock(send_blocks[i_]).then(function (send_block) {
                user_xp = user_xp + send_block.gasUsed
                console.log(user_xp)
            })
        }
    })).then(
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(user_xp)
        xp = document.getElementById('xp')
        xp.innerHTML = "XP:" + user_xp
    },1000)
)
```

In the above code, I am just using `setTimeout()` which is solving my problem. But I want the code to execute automatically only when the above promises are resolved. Is there any easy way to do that in JS w/o putting promises in functions and making it more complex.

**UPDATE**

I am using the following web3's function to fetch data from the solidity's smart contract which actually returns a promise with the data as `promiseValue`

[myContract.methods.myMethod([parameters).call(options,[callback])](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)

Comment: using Promise.then inside the `for` loops doesn't wait for those promises to be resolved ... consider using async/await (if the code in the loop needs to run in series) or Promise.all with array.map if you can run those promises concurrently - though, your for loops aren't simple as in one case you're adding 2 to the index each iteration so that may need some filtering

Comment: also, your `.then`s are completely wrong since you aren't passing a function to them - I'm guessing that `connections_blocks.methods.get_deposit_blocks(current_email).call` returns a promise?

Comment: Yes, I can run promises concurrently. And I don't know what it means to return a promise!

Comment: a function returns something ... it can be anything ... even a promise

Comment: your pseudo code does not accurately described the actual code - the psuedo code is easily fixed, the actual code requires far more information

Comment: before answering this question, need to know what `connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks` is, what it takes as arguments, what it returns, can you pass a callback to it and will it still return a promise, if there's asyncrhonous code in the callback, how does that effect the promise returned by the function ... etc

Comment: your edited code does not address the issues I had in my now deleted answer - no, that code you wrote does not fix your problem because of the issues I mentioned

Comment: @JaromandaX I added the reference of `connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks`. Sorry, I should have added it before and I removed the code in UPDATE as it was not solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your code include

1. the arguments to .then must be functions
2. if you need to wait for the Promises in the loop, you need to add them to an array and then use promise.all to wait until they're all resolved

Try the following changes to your *actual* code - I'm assuming that without the node style callback, the function returns a promise that resolves to the `result` that would be passed to the node-style callback (which is removed in this code)

(if you wait a while I'll flatten the promise chain - just noticed it isn't as flat as it could be

```
user_xp = 0
return connections_blocks.methods.get_deposit_blocks(current_email).call({
    from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
})
.then(function (result) {
    var promises = []
    deposit_blocks = result
    console.log(deposit_blocks)
    deposit_blocks = deposit_blocks.split(",")
    deposit_blocks.splice(0, 1)
    for (i_ in deposit_blocks) {
        console.log(deposit_blocks[i_])
        promises.push(
            new_web3.eth.getBlock(deposit_blocks[i_]).then(function (deposit_block) {
                user_xp = user_xp + deposit_block.gasUsed
                console.log(user_xp)
            })
        )
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
})
.then(function () {
    return connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks(current_email).call({
        from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
    })
})
.then(function (result) {
    var promises=[]
    send_blocks = result
    console.log(send_blocks)
    send_blocks = send_blocks.split(",")
    send_blocks.splice(0, 1)
    for (i_ = 0; i_ < send_blocks.length; i_ = i_ + 2) {
        console.log(send_blocks[i_])
        promises.push(
            new_web3.eth.getBlock(send_blocks[i_]).then(function (send_block) {
                user_xp = user_xp + send_block.gasUsed
                console.log(user_xp)
            })
        )
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
})
.then(function () {
    console.log(user_xp)
    xp = document.getElementById('xp')
    xp.innerHTML = "XP:" + user_xp
})
```

As an added "bonus", I believe the code can be simplified to

```
return connections_blocks.methods.get_deposit_blocks(current_email).call({
    from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
})
.then(result => Promise.all(result.split(",").slice(1).map(deposit_block => new_web3.eth.getBlock(deposit_block)
    .then(deposit_block => deposit_block.gasUsed)
})
.then(gasUsed1Array => connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks(current_email).call({
        from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
    })
    .then(result => Promise.all(result.split(",").slice(1).filter((v, i) => !(i%2)).map(send_blocks => new_web3.eth.getBlock(send_block)
        .then(send_block => send_block.gasUsed)
    )))
    .then(gasUsed2Array => [...gasUsed1Array, ...gasUsed2Array])
)
.then(results => {
    user_xp = results.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    console.log(user_xp)
    xp = document.getElementById('xp')
    xp.innerHTML = "XP:" + user_xp
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like magic. I was just thinking to use `.then()` instead of a callback function. And I am still a little confused that how we are using returned promise in next `.then()`. I think it is passed to result parameter

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the resolve of Promise_1 and Promise_3 will wait for the callbacks to complete. If this is the case, this should work.

```
user_xp = 0

connections_blocks.methods.get_deposit_blocks(current_email).call({
    from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
}, function (err, result) {
    deposit_blocks = result
    console.log(deposit_blocks)
    deposit_blocks = deposit_blocks.split(",")
    deposit_blocks.splice(0, 1)
    // array to hold the promises
    const subPromises = []
    for (i_ in deposit_blocks) {
        console.log(deposit_blocks[i_])
        subPromises.push(new_web3.eth.getBlock(deposit_blocks[i_]))
    }
    // waiting for all promises to resolve
    Promise.all(subPromises).then(function (deposit_block) {
        user_xp = user_xp + deposit_block.gasUsed
        console.log(user_xp)
    })
})
.then(
    connections_blocks.methods.get_send_blocks(current_email).call({
        from: new_web3.eth.Contract.defaultAccount
    }, function (err, result) {
        send_blocks = result
        console.log(send_blocks)
        send_blocks = send_blocks.split(",")
        send_blocks.splice(0, 1)
        const subPromises = []
        for (i_ = 0; i_ < send_blocks.length; i_ = i_ + 2) {
            console.log(send_blocks[i_])
            subPromises.push(
                new_web3.eth.getBlock(send_blocks[i_])
            )
        }
        Promise.all(subPromises).then(function (send_block) {
            user_xp = user_xp + send_block.gasUsed
            console.log(user_xp)
        })
    })
)
.then(function () {
    console.log(user_xp)
    xp = document.getElementById('xp')
    xp.innerHTML = "XP:" + user_xp
})
```